# What am I missing in my CSS animation?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, css-animations

I'm trying to get the title on my page to animate from white, through the rainbow, then back to white. Here's my code:

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         background-color: whitesmoke;
     }
13% {
        background-color: red;
    }
25% {
        background-color: orange;
    }
38% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        background-color: green;
    }
63% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
75% {
        background-color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        background-color: violet;
    }
to {
       background-color: white;
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         background-color: whitesmoke;
     }
13% {
        background-color: red;
    }
25% {
        background-color: orange;
    }
38% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        background-color: green;
    }
63% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
75% {
        background-color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        background-color: violet;
    }
to {
       background-color: white;
   }
}

@-o-keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         background-color: whitesmoke;
     }
13% {
        background-color: red;
    }
25% {
        background-color: orange;
    }
38% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        background-color: green;
    }
63% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
75% {
        background-color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        background-color: violet;
    }
to {
       background-color: white;
   }
}

@keyframes rainbowGlow {
from {
         background-color: whitesmoke;
     }
13% {
        background-color: red;
    }
25% {
        background-color: orange;
    }
38% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
50% {
        background-color: green;
    }
63% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
75% {
        background-color: indigo;
    }
88% {
        background-color: violet;
    }
to {
       background-color: white;
   }
}

.WhiteRainbowGlow {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Candara, Consolas, Calibri, sans-serif !important;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 6px #000000;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;

    animation-name: rainbowGlow;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="WhiteRainbowGlow">My Next Winner</h1>
```

Am I forgetting something? Doing something wrong?

Comment: I dint get your question. But if you are talking about the color change, then its working in my Chrome. Have you tested it in different browsers? Do you want the transition to work this way? WROYGBIV to W or WROYGBIV to IBGYORW?

Comment: I use Chrome mainly, too, and it's not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.WhiteRainbowGlow {

...

    -moz-animation: rainbowGlow 1s;
    -o-animation: rainbowGlow  1s;
    -webkit-animation: rainbowGlow 1s;
    animation: rainbowGlow 1s;

}
```

Comment: That works, but moz and webkit are grayed out; which is odd, because I'm testing with Chrome, and webkit is Chrome, right?

Comment: webkit based browsers, like chrome and safari

Comment: Right, so why would firefox, Chrome, and Opera be dissed that way, by having their vendor-specific prefix be grayed out?

Comment: Because in the time they got release, for example animation was not a css standard, and since it is not standard they use prefixes to prevent violent!for more information you can go to w3schools.com, if by grayed out you mean grayed out in the CLR that's because your css environment tries to help you

Answer (score 1):

Add this to WhiteRainbowGlow

```
    -webkit-animation: rainbowGlow 5s 1 linear;
    -moz-animation: rainbowGlow 5s 1 linear;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXkJg/) example